# jquery bbq cant get pretty urls; using pushstate

Tags: jquery, ajax, string, url

Thank You.

urls look like this: 
http://mysite.com/#main=mysite.php%3Fid%3D108&main=mysite.php%3Fid%3D108

Im trying to get them to look like this:
 http://mysite.com/#main=mysite.php?id=108&main=mysite.php?id=108

Here is the code:

```
  $(function(){
      $('.bbq').each(function(){
        $(this).data( 'bbq', {
          cache: {
            '': $(this).find('.bbq-default')
          }
        });
      });

  // For all links inside a .bbq widget, push the appropriate state onto the
  // history when clicked.
      $('.bbq a[href^=#]').live( 'click', function(e){
        var state = {},

          // Get the id of this .bbq widget.
          id = $(this).closest( '.bbq' ).attr( 'id' ),

          // Get the url from the link's href attribute, stripping any leading #.
          url = $(this).attr( 'href' ).replace( /^#/, '' );

        // Set the state!
        state[ id ] = url;
        $.bbq.pushState( state );

        return false;
      });

  $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {

    // Iterate over all .bbq widgets.
      var that = $(this),

        // Get the stored data for this .bbq widget.
        data = that.data( 'bbq' ),

        // Get the url for this .bbq widget from the hash, based on the
        // appropriate id property. In jQuery 1.4, you should use e.getState()
        // instead of $.bbq.getState().
        url = $.bbq.getState( that.attr( 'id' ) ) || '';

      // If the url hasn't changed, do nothing and skip to the next .bbq widget.
      if ( data.url === url ) { return; }

      // Store the url for the next time around.
      data.url = url;

      // Remove .bbq-current class from any previously "current" link(s).
      that.find( 'a.bbq-current' ).removeClass( 'bbq-current' );

      // Hide any visible ajax content.
      that.find( '.bbq-content' ).children( ':visible' ).hide();

      // Add .bbq-current class to "current" nav link(s), only if url isn't empty.
      url && that.find( 'a[href="#' + url + '"]' ).addClass( 'bbq-current' );

      if ( data.cache[ url ] ) {
        // Since the widget is already in the cache, it doesn't need to be
        // created, so instead of creating it again, let's just show it!
        data.cache[ url ].show();

      } else {
        // Show "loading" content while AJAX content loads.
        that.find( '.bbq-loading' ).show();

        // Create container for this url's content and store a reference to it in
        // the cache.
        data.cache[ url ] = $( '<div class="bbq-item"/>' )

          // Append the content container to the parent container.
          .appendTo( that.find( '.bbq-content' ) )

          // Load external content via AJAX. Note that in order to keep this
          // example streamlined, only the content in .infobox is shown. You'll
          // want to change this based on your needs.
          .load( url, function(){
            // Content loaded, hide "loading" content.
            that.find( '.bbq-loading' ).hide();
          });
      }
    });
  })

            $(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );

});
```

**Edit**

I should have made that more clear:
http://mysite.com/#main=page1.php?id=108&main2=page2.php?id=108
loading other pages with strings.

Comment: You are trying to change links on the current page?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for pretty URLs, but the URL format you're asking for is far from "pretty".

You're asking for your URL to look like this:

```
http://mysite.com/#main=page1.php?id=108&main2=page2.php?id=108
```

Basically your URL format tells me that you're on a page which is referencing another URL within its own URL, and that URL it's referencing is itself referencing a third URL. This is a very complex URL scheme, and is likely to confuse your users. What is it that you're trying to achieve with it?

The purpose of adding components to the URL hash in an ajax site in this way is to give the user a something he can link to or bookmark. Ask yourself whether the parameters you've given will help with that.

It looks to me like you could achieve much the same thing with simply `id=108` in your URL hash. Everything else is fluff that the user shouldn't need to see in the URL. Your Javascript code can rebuild the ajax URLs internally without the user having to know about them.